# Modularity for spring boot multi module

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, java-9, multi-module, modularity

I have Spring boot multi module micro service application like below
parent module
-childmodule1
-childmodule2
-childmodule3
Currently each child modules are depolyed as single jar.
I need to implement java 9 modularity feature for each child module.
As per my understanding we need to create separate modules for each childmodule and each seperate module can be deployed as separate jars.

say if childmodule1 had  two modules moduleA and moduleB , Then it can be deployed as two jars?
How does the childmodule1 having two jars communicates   with other childmodules?

Do I really need java 9 modularity feature to the springboot mutli module projects. If yes ,how can i make use of the modularity benefits to my application.
Im new to micro service architecture and java 9 modularity. Can someone please help on this